# issue with jquery cookie plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, samsung-smart-tv, jquery-cookie

I'm using jquery `cookie` plugin to save data, the data is saved and i can read it but it's goes when i'm close the browser and open it again, i do programming for `Samsung smart TV app`, and the api support cookie, also as i said i can read the data throw the cookie, i set the expiry date too 100 day, but when I close the TV and open it again there is no data, the TV use `Mozilla`, here is my code.

```
 jQuery.cookie("user", data, { expires: 100 });
```

while data is json object from the ajax call, i parse it to string and save it and it's worked fine when i'm read it, but the problem is when i'm closing the TV and open it again there is no data saved.

Comment: maybe you are overwriting every time your code starts, provide more code please...

Comment: i don't think so, i saved the data just when he logged in, then i get the data from other function after i close the TV and open it again

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `sf.core.localData("user", data);` instead of cookies. Just see [guide](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00009/sfcore_localdata.html).

Then you have to emulate expiration on your own - maybe save timestamp in your `data` and then compare it with current timestamp when TV/app is starting. If data expired, just do what you need.

As far as I know the `common area` mentioned in guide is the only way to store persistent data.

Comment: Thanks Wirone, unfortunately I'm not using the app framework, so i cant use sf, and it will be a problem if it's just the only way